# How to forbid hide content of the html table column when column size is auto?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page and its width is limited. Also, a table on that page so the width of the table limited by the width of the page. Then I have several columns in that table the width of the column is calculated automatically. If the width of the column's content (let's say these are text strings without breaks) is bigger than the width of the page then part of the strings will be hidden. I want to forbid hide the content for some particular column. In other words, I want that column takes as much width as it needs and the other columns split the rest of the space among them.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

> a block-level element always takes up the full width available
>   (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).
>
> Setting the width of a block-level element will prevent it from
>   stretching out to the edges of its container. Then, you can set the
>   margins to auto, to horizontally center the element within its
>   container. The element will take up the specified width, and the
>   remaining space will be split equally between the two margins:

source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp

```css
div.ex1 {
    width:500px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.ex2 {
    max-width:500px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ex1">This div element has width: 500px;</div>
<br>

<div class="ex2">This div element has max-width: 500px;</div>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Drag the browser window to smaller than 500px wide, to see the difference between 
the two divs!</p>

</body>
</html>
```